# JQUERY datepicker calendar, how can I rename the “today” button to “present”

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to change "Today" button text in Jquery datepicker to "Present".
and also customise the functionality

Any thoughts please

Comment: Do you have an example?  I don't recall seeing any button in the default datepicker:  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Sure please click on this link  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar

Comment: I got it it's currentText ="Present" code example :$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        currentText: 'present',
        closeText : 'Close',
        dateFormat: 'MM yy', }

Answer (score 4):

Answer from the comment. It may be helpful to some people

```
currentText: "Present"
```

code example:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    currentText: 'present',
    closeText : 'Close',
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
});
```